# The C language, does implicit conversion in assignments

Tags: c

The C language, does implicit conversion in assignments, both from smaller types to larger types and from larger types to smaller ones, is that it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int x = 5;
   long y = x; // conversion implicit ?

   long a = 12;
   int b = a; // conversion implicit ?
   return 0;
}
```

Another thing, have you written in the language standard about conversions when using the assignment operator?

Comment: Here's something that's probably easier to read than the standard: [C language - Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Comment: Which says (for your second example) *if the target type can represent the value, the value is unchanged, ... otherwise if the target type is signed, the behavior is implementation-defined*.

Comment: @TedLyngmo In the reference you gave me, right at the bottom of the footer is the following text "There are no conversions (implicit or explicit) between pointers to functions and pointers to objects (including void*) or integers." I don't understand the void * part, in C, the pointer to void * is not implicitly cast, something like char *s = malloc(200) ? Or am I wrong, this conversion business is getting to me, thanks for your attention

Comment: @YuriBittencourt Function pointers are a bit special. Here's [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/za75zWfKM)

Comment: Yes, it does automatic things like this.  They are defined in the ISO9899.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to explain what the C standard says formally. We can start by reading 6.5.16.1/2:

> In *simple assignment* (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

*Simple assignment* meaning `=`, as opposed to the various *compound assignments* like for example `+=`.

The above mentioned conversion only happens if the assignment is a valid form. There's a list of all forms of valid assignments (you don't need to read it, I'm including it here for the sake of completeness):

> **6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**

> **Constraints**

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has
>   arithmetic type;
> - the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type
>   compatible with the type of the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type
>   the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified
>   or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the
>   qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type
>   the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type,
>   and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to
>   by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null pointer
>   constant; or
> - the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified _Bool, and the right is a pointer.

If a type of assignment is not on that list, it is a "constraint violation", meaning invalid C, and the compiler must issue a message about it.

If an assignment is on that list, the right operand is implicitly converted to the type of the left operand. In your case `long y = x;`, it fits the first bullet in the list: the left operand is an arithmetic type (integer or float) and the right operand is also arithmetic type. So the `int` operand `x` gets converted to `long` upon assignment.

---

Regarding qualifiers:

All the stuff about "qualified type" refers to `const` etc type qualifiers. During assignment, something called *lvalue conversion* occurs. 6.5.16/3:

> The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have
> after lvalue conversion.

Not very helpful if you don't know what an "lvalue conversion" is. The formal definition is found in 6.3.2.1/2, but it's equally unhelpful for beginners. To summarize it in simple terms, lvalue conversion means that it doesn't matter what qualifiers (`const`, `volatile` etc) the right operand has, it gets converted to have the same qualifiers as the left operand. The term "lvalue" actually originates from "left value of the assignment operator".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, just to confirm, any pointer to void, if it has the operand on the right, will be implicitly converted after assignment to the type of lvalue, correct ? For example the malloc function, returns void*, and in this case void * can be converted to any lvalue pointer, correct ?, now if on the right side it had a pointer to int *, and on the left side a pointer to char *, in this if the implicit conversion would not occur, correct?

Comment: “The above mentioned conversion only happens if the assignment is a valid form.” is not correct. Typically, a conversion happens if the compiler accepts the code. E.g., if a pointer is assigned to an integer, and the compiler warns about it but still accepts the program and produces an object module, it includes a conversion from the pointer to an integer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But that's wildly undefined behavior beyond the scope of the standard and not meaningful to discuss when teaching beginners how to write valid standard C.

Answer (score -1):

From my knowledge it does, you can use print statements and see the warning about the types.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int x = 5;
   printf("%d ",x);
   long y = x; // conversion implicit ?
   printf("%d ",y);


   long a = 12;
   printf("%ld ",a);
   int b = a; // conversion implicit ?
   printf("%ld ",b);
   return 0;
}
```